Why is Vercel not deploying my recipes.json file?
I'm working on building a recipe website where users can add recipes to it. This website is hosted on Vercel and for some reason, Vercel is not Deploying the recipes.json (or anything from the public folder. Is there something I am missing to get Vercel to deploy this? The recipes.json is essential for loading all the recipes on the site, if that wasn't obvious.
File Structure
Vercel Deployment Summary

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
